# Discrete valuation ring associated to a principal divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $V$ is a normal variety, and $Z$ is a principal divisor so a closed subvariety of $V$ with codimension $1$.Then I don't understand the following construction of the valuation ring $\mathcal O_Z$:

[image]

In particular my problem is the following: since $V$ is normal, $R=\mathcal O_X(U)=\Gamma( U,\mathcal O)$ is integrally closed but I don't understand why $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a discrete valuation ring. Moreover why is it important the fact that $\mathfrak p$ is a minimal ideal?

Comment: I don't know what kind of answer you're looking for, but if you look at the Wikipedia page for DVR you see various equivalent definitions, for instance "$R$ is an integrally closed noetherian local ring with Krull dimension one". This shows why minimality of $\mathfrak{p}$ is relevant: if it contained a smaller prime ideal, then the localisation would have Krull dimension at least 2.

Comment: Maybe you also want to know concretely what the valuation is. Briefly, fix a generator $t$ for the prinicipal ideal $\mathfrak{p} R$: then every element $x \in R_\mathfrak{p}$ can be written in the form $at^k$ for a unique nonnegative integer $k$. We define the valuation as $v(x) = k$.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically pure algebra. By a theorem in chapter 9 of Atiyah Macdonald (I think Proposition 9.2 or 9.3) a Noetherian local domain of dimension 1 is a DVR iff it is integrally closed.

So in your case above we are given a minimal prime $\mathfrak{p}$ (which is necessarily of height $1$) and hence $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is one-dimensional (basically height = dimensional of localization at prime). Since $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is integrally closed by the proposition above we have that $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a DVR.

Comment: "A Noetherian local domain is a DVR iff it is integrally closed"...that doesn't sound right: did you leave out "1-dimensional"?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Ah yes. As usual I leave out the important hypotheses :D